# $\lim_{x\to{0^+}}{\sin(\log(x))}$

Tags: limits

How can I solve this: $\lim_{x\to{0^+}}{\sin(\log(x))}$ ?

Since $\log(x)\to -\infty$ I don’t know how to evaluate the limit of $\sin(x)$

Comment: Well, just evaluate $\limsup$ and $\liminf$, then, and see what you get.

Answer (score 2):

The sequences $x_n=e^{-(2n+1/2)\pi},\,x_n=e^{-(2n-1/2)\pi}$ have respective $x\to0^+$ limits for $\sin\ln x$ of $-1,\,1$, so the proposed limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Is $\lim_{n \infty} x_n=0^{\pi i}=0$, OK?

Comment: @ZAhmed I've removed errant $i$s from my answer. I think you meant the example$$x_n=e^{-n\pi}\implies\sin\ln x_n=0.$$Any subsequences tending to $0^+$ for which $\sin\ln x$ has different limits will prove the result.

Comment: can you explain to me how you calculated it?

Comment: @Francesco For example,$$\sin\ln e^{-(2n+1/2)\pi}=\sin[-(2n+1/2)\pi]=-\sin[(2n+1/2)\pi]=-\sin(\pi/2)=-1.$$